# How does std::vector reallocates every time an item is inserted using a loop?

Tags: c++, vector

I've read that `std::vector` reallocation works like this:

> How expensive is reallocation? It involves four steps:
>
> 1. Allocate enough memory for the desired new capacity;
> 2. Copy the elements from the old memory to the new;
> 3. Destroy the elements in the old memory; and
> 4. Deallocate the old memory.

So that it may be a good practice to use `.reserve()` somewhat like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int unnkownNumberOfElementsToAdd = 30; //it's 30 now, but suppose you don't know

vec.reserve(unnkownNumberOfElementsToAdd);
for(int i=0; i<unnkownNumberOfElementsToAdd; i++ )
{
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```

So that it doesn't reallocate the entire vector everytime an item is inserted.
But the funny thing is, if you **DON'T** `.reserve()` and you print `vec.size`and `vec.capacity` everytime `i` is inserted, this is the output:

```
size | capacity
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 6
6 6
7 9
8 9
9 9
10 13
11 13
12 13
13 13
14 19
15 19
16 19
17 19
18 19
19 19
20 28
21 28
22 28
23 28
24 28
25 28
26 28
27 28
28 28
29 42
30 42
```

I don't know if the capacity increase is compiler dependent (I'm using old VS2003). In case it's not, how does this reallocation works?

Comment: Imho one should not worry about implementation details too much, because it might be that they change without having any notice of it, so you might end up expecting certain behavior when actually something else is going on (because different compiler, different version of same compiler, different whatever)

Comment: @Manos: Yes, the destructors get called. It would be a disaster if `vector`s didn't destroy the old objects. (excepting, of course, classes that have a trivial destructor)

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis: No. You are wrong. `std::vector` definitely calls the destructors of the objects in the previous memory location. If this causes problems with your objects, then you have not properly implemented value semantics for your class. For example, if you have a vector of `fstream` objects, the files will not be closed when the vector reallocates, because they're move constructed to the new location. This move construction causes the `fstream` objects in the old location to release their hold on the file resource, causing their destructor to pretty much be a no-op.

Comment: There are actually very enlighted implementations of vectors out there. Some of them go great lengths to know what they need to do with objects when they are reallocated. They might be swapped, they might be move-constructed, or (I seen those) some of them figure out if object is bit-wise copyable and do bit-wise copy just forgetting all about original.

Comment: @Manos: ...whereas by comparison if you have a vector of strings, say, then after moving everything, all of those objects in the old memory still hold resources (dynamically allocated memory) that would would get permanently lost if the destructors didn't get called.

Comment: I verified that destructors do get called (gcc 4.8.3) so I stand corrected. I guess it's a good reason to avoid push_back when calling a destructor is expensive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::vector` does not reallocate every time an element is added. It reallocates when it runs out of capacity. And when it reallocates, it doesn't allocate space for just 1 more element. It typically allocates by some factor of the the current capacity. I believe VS uses a factor of 1.5, and some others use 2. It has to do this in order to ensure that `push_back` has amortized O(1) complexity, which is a requirement of the standard.

If you know for certain exactly how many elements you are going to add to the vector over its lifetime, it is still a good idea to reserve though, imo. Some might consider that premature optimization. But it is such a simple thing to do, I consider not doing it to be premature pessimization.

Comment: very enlightening, "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes" - S.O said.

Comment: `It reallocates when it runs out of capacity`, enforces that it is a good idea to use `.reserve()` since this entire loop is done without a single reallocation

Comment: besides your valid argunments ,it also shows intend and can be helpfull with debugging.

Comment: Do be careful when using reserve, as if used incorrectly you can turn push_back from O(1) to O(n) and therefore increase complexity for creating a vector of n items from O(n) to O(n^2)! So its not just premature optimization sometimes its downright _wrong_.

Comment: I've added an answer showing this below, be sure to take a look and learn when not to do this.

Comment: @MikeVine: I've added a slight clarification, so hopefully people don't get confused about when reserving is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the capacity is increased by a constant factor every time the current size exceeds the maximum capacity. But it's compiler dependent, particularly in the smaller numbers. So is the initial capacity. E.g. `g++` will reserve an initial size of 8 elements AFAIK.

Multiplying the storage by a factor leads to constant amortized complexity for insertion, but there is a trade-off between the effective work for insertion and the unused capacity. For large vectors the reserved, but unused capacity may be large (up to the constant factor being used).  This is why this is a compiler defined  behaviour. Compilers optimising for memory constrained systems (e.g. embedded systems) may chose to reduce this factor at the cost of increasing the runtime due to more allocations.

If you know the size, just use `reserve` to avoid depending on compiler specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`reserve()` is somehow outdated by now, as vector reallocation strategies are well-tailored for majority of usage.

However, they come with drawback. For instance, when I was dealing with 32-bit systems, I had an extremely large data structure (large because it holded a lot of elements) in memory, and one the members of it's elements was a vector. Vectors were incredibly short - many of them empty, some having one or two elements. Yet the implementation pre-allocated 32 elements, and caused my program to run out of memory (simply because I had insane number of those vectors). Replacing vector with list degraded my random access, but allowed the program to run.

Comment: outdated ? ridiculous statement ! It's not ,nor will it ever be.

Comment: @engf-010 it is outdated in a sense that using it almost always constitutes a premature optimization. Usually efforts needed to know the size of the vector in advance do not justify the benefit. Also note 'somewhat'.

Comment: it almost always constitutes a premature optimization ? You shouldn't make such statements ,because you haven't seen almost every usage.

Comment: @engf-010, all generalizations are false. Including this one.

Answer (score 1):

Be really *really* careful when using `reserve`. If you use it incorrectly in a loop you can massively increase your execution time due to forcing reallocation to be arithmetic rather than geometric:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Add2Items(std::vector<int>& vec, bool reserve)
{
    if(reserve)
    {
        // Surely reserving upfront the sapce for the 2 items I'm going to add is a _good thing_
        vec.reserve(vec.size() + 2);
    }
    vec.push_back(42);
    vec.push_back(42);
}

int main()
{
    for(int iter=0; iter<2; ++iter)
    {
        bool reserve = iter ? false : true;

        auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::vector<int> vec;
        for(int i=0; i<1024 * 64; ++i)
        {
            Add2Items(vec, reserve);
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Iteration " << iter << " with " << (reserve ? "reserve" : "no reserve") << " took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Iteration 0 with reserve took 2432ms
Iteration 1 with no reserve took 133ms
```

Comment: Great example of bad code ! It demonstrates defeating the purpose of reserve. Anyone who writes such code (except in a learning process) should be promoted to delivery-boy.

Comment: That constructed snippet is silly. Usually reserve should not consider increments, but an expected size (which might be adjusted with shrink_to_fit afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great way to understand how vectors automatically allocate. This is, of course, done the way for efficiency, and the output will vary for systems, but it'll give you a general idea.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    int i = 0;
    while (v.size() <= 100)
    {
        std::cout << "Size: " << v.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Capacity: " << v.capacity() << std::endl;
        v.push_back(i++);
    }
}
```

It'll typically print something like this:

```
Size: 0
Capacity: 0
Size: 1
Capacity: 1
Size: 2
Capacity: 2
Size: 3
Capacity: 4
Size: 4
Capacity: 4
Size: 5
Capacity: 8
Size: 6
Capacity: 8
Size: 7
Capacity: 8
Size: 8
Capacity: 8
Size: 9
Capacity: 16
Size: 10
Capacity: 16
Size: 11
Capacity: 16
Size: 12
Capacity: 16
Size: 13
Capacity: 16
Size: 14
Capacity: 16
Size: 15
Capacity: 16
Size: 16
Capacity: 16
Size: 17
Capacity: 32
Size: 18
Capacity: 32 
...
```